# Using ActionBar Inside Fragment class in android

Tags: android, tabs, fragment, android-fragmentactivity, viewswitcher

I am trying to create Sliding tabs inside fragment . By referring tutorial from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=heR4zhj_wV0) link. I am using `ViewPager` it. 
    Below is the my code :-

```
   public class A extends Fragment {


    private ViewPager pager;
    private TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.one_fragment,
                null);

        pager = new ViewPager(getActivity());
        pager.setId(R.id.pager);
        getActivity().setContentView(pager);

        final ActionBar bar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(getActivity(), pager);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Mixed"), MixedFragment.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Income"), MixedFragment.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Expense"), MixedFragment.class, null);


        return v;
    }


}
```

When I run the application it gives null pointer exception at

```
 final ActionBar bar = getActivity().getActionBar();
            bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

Please anyone tell me how to solve this problem.
Or give me some sample code to create sliding tabs inside `Fragment`(Not `FragmentActivity`).
Thanks in advance.

Below is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hm.example"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <activity
            android:name="com.hm.example.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Below is what my logcat is showing :

```
   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.hm.A.onCreateView(A.java:49)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1884)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1514)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is the theme that is set for activity?

Comment: post the manifest file

Comment: @Raghunandan : in values it is Theme.Light.NoTitleBar                                in values v-11 it is Theme.Holo.Light                                in values v-14 it is Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen

Comment: You have no actionbar for the activity. hence returns null. Change the theme and it should work. check my post

Comment: my post is right below. did you check the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getActionBar()` can return null.

> public ActionBar getActionBar ()
>
> Added in API level 11 Retrieve a reference to this activity's
>   ActionBar.
>
> **Returns The Activity's ActionBar, or null if it does not have one**.

You might be using a non actionbar theme for the activity.

Have a actionbar theme

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
```

Comment: hey it's not working. . still having the same error as null. .

Comment: @user3458918 hey you are not doing it right. that is why its not working. Did you copy paste `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"` in manifest for activity and then check??

Comment: Yes I did it. I have edited my question and inserted my edited manifest file as you suggested.

Comment: @user3458918 then post the stacktrace the crash may be for a different reason getActionBar cannot return null now

Comment: it is returning null as I have set debugger at that point and it is showing null for bar. I am posting what my logcat is showing. Please see my edited question.

Comment: @user3458918 what is  line 49 `A.java`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51475/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-user3458918)

Comment: @user3458918 join the chat in the above link. You are doing it wrong